# Converting UCS2LE to a string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, unicode, character-encoding

I have a BLOB field in MySQL that contains embedded strings in effectively UCS-2 little-endian format (AKA Windows wide strings). I want to extract them in a SQL query as regular strings. MySQL's built-in `ucs2` charset [assumes big-endian](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html).

The whole thing is on a hosted server where I'm not allowed to create user-defined functions (e. g. one that would swap bytes).

Any alternatives, please? Perhaps, a clever regex?

EDIT: there's no regex-based replace in MySQL, only matching.

EDIT2: looks like on more recent versions of MySQL, `utf16le` is available as a charset. Not in mine.

Comment: 1999 called. They want their Windows wide strings back. Windows wide strings have been UTF-16 since Windows 2000.

Comment: Tell that to the wcslen() function.

Comment: The `wcslen` function, which is part of the C standard library, gives you the number of `wchar_t` objects before the null terminator. I don't see how it changes anything.

Comment: And so does the whole body of Win32; none of the ...W functions treat widestrings other than arrays of wchar_t. Also, how often do you encounter non-BMP characters in real life? It's irrelevant to the question, anyway. MySQL does not have a built-in UTF16 charset.